# How to prove this manifold is a sphere?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $M$ is a compact topological manifold, and it is covered by two open set $A$ and $B$, both homeomorphic to $n$-dimensional discs. How can I show that $M$ is homeomorphic to a $n$-dimendional sphere?

Comment: The manifold should be boundaryless.

Comment: i think this is more subtle than the simple statement suggests: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117457/manifolds-with-two-coordinate-charts

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi_A\colon D^n\to A\subseteq M$, $\phi_B\colon D^n\to B\subseteq M$ be homeomorphisms accordingly.
For $v\in S^{n-1}$, let $\psi(v)=\lim_{t\to1}\phi_A(tv) $. Then $\psi(v)\in B$ and there exists an open neighbourhood $U_v$ of $v\in S^{n-1}$ and a $r_v\in(0,1)$ such that $\phi_A(tw)\in B$ for all $(t,w)\in (r_v,1)\times U_v$. By compactness, $S^{n-1}$ is covered by finitely many such sets and we obtain that $\phi_A(rS^{n-1})\subseteq B$ for some $0<r<1$ ($r$ need only be greater than finitely many $r_v$).
Now we have a homeomorphic image $S:=\phi_A(rS^{n-1})$ of $S^{n-1}$ contauined in $A\cap B$.
Now we let $A'=\{x\in A\mid \lVert \phi_A^{-1}(x)\rVert <r\}$, $B'=B\setminus (A'\cup S)$  and can construct a homeomorphism $M\to S^n$ by viewing $S$ as equator and $A',B'$ as hemispheres (attention: why is $B'$ homeomorphic to a disk?)

Comment: Why is B' still a disk?

Comment: I think that should follow with Jordan-Brouwer, but I'm not too happy with my whole answer any more ...

Comment: Do you aware of the existence of Alexander's horned sphere?